# How can I set a directory maximum size?

Tags: filesystems, directory, administration

Is there an easy way to cap the size of a directory?  I don't think there is but just wanted to make sure.  I would like to set max directory sizes for some user home dirs as well as some other dirs, mostly under `/var` in an attempt to better manage the disk resources.

Comment: Are [quotas](http://wiki.robotz.com/index.php/Quota-_Linux_User_Quota_HowTo) acceptable solution?

Comment: See also this (possible duplicate?) [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/q/100596/97710) question on *per-directory quotas*.

Comment: @dchirikov -- if a quota will effectively cap a dir size, then yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a separate filesystem for /var on a new disk partition/LUN created for this. Then, you can use LVM to manage the size. In future, if you feel the need to grow this filesystem, LVM will be more flexible for that.

Comment: This is probably what I would do. I was going to post this an an answer, and then I scrolled down and saw that you beat me to it. :)